# Raspberry Pi not booting up over USB power supply

Tags: pi-3, power-supply, usb-power, android-things

I am doing some stuff with *Raspberry Pi*. I have successfully burn my OS on SD card. I am able to boot up the system when I provide power with charging adapter. But when I powered up with my laptop USB port then its not booting up. I am trying with new *Android Things* version 0.5. Is this the power issue or some thing else need to be done. Also if it is a power issue then how to power and do some coding on *Pi* in this situations?

Comment: This most likely is a power issue. A USB 2 port can only supply 0.5A.

Comment: whats the solution then ?

Comment: I am building some thing on top of Android Things and It required adb interface.

Comment: Have you tried the charger that works as power supply and a regular USB cable for the ADB interface?

Comment: But there only one J1 which I can connect either charger or my computer.

Comment: _"I am building some thing on top of Android Things and It required ADB interface"_. [You can't have ADB over USB in RPi3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44249334/3290339).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended official Power supply for a Pi 3 supplies 2.5A.  A standard USB port is limited to 500mA.  The pi3 is best powered through the dedicated micro-usb power port with a power supply capable of 2A minimum.  N.B. All raspberry pi's can be back powered through the full sized USB ports if connected to a hub or other connection providing back power.  This can lead to boot problems with the pi failing to boot when main power is cycled if already receiving insufficient power through the main USB sockets.  To overcome this problem connect main power to start the boot process and then connect the  any back power device (e.g. laptop/PC and some USB hubs), without waiting for boot to complete, to the full sized USB ports.

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/power/README.md for further information

Comment: @nilkash I see your comment 'But there only one J1 which I can connect either charger or my computer'  but you have added the pi-3 tag to your question.  The pi-3 has a micro-usb power port and  4 full sized ports.  The micro-usb port on a pi-3 is for power only.