# Why is my Raspberry Pi booting an infinite number of times when I turn it on?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-4, boot-issues, reboot

I recently got a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B board in 2022, and I did not use my Raspberry much. When I put the OS in the Raspberry, it works. But When I tried using it now with a new OS and a new sd card. It did not work. Like it was rebooting, again and again, an infinite amount of times, also, it is a new OS and I updated my Imager but still, it did not work... It shows all the time "Welcome to the Raspberry Pi desktop" or something like that and then it shows the rainbow screen. It has done this for a long time...

Comment: I doubt it is infinite because you would have to wait until the end of the universe to see. If you want help explain exactly WHAT YOU DID, what OS and how you installed it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered many times.  Search for pi not booting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi not booting up over USB power supply](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71674/raspberry-pi-not-booting-up-over-usb-power-supply)

Comment: @Milliways - we could never prove that something will happen an 'infinite' number of times.